# could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

Tags: xml, testng, automated-tests

I'm trying to execute `testng-qc-sanity-regression.xml from`cmd` in this way:

> runtest.bat testng-qc-sanity-regression.xml

and I get this error:

> could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

but I don't really know why. I've tried with:

> java -jar myjar.jar -cp ./bin testng-qc-sanity-regression.xml

it did not work.

and I also tried with:

> java -cp
>   D:\Profiles\user.m2\repository\org\testng\testng\6.8.5\testng-6.8.5.jar;
>   org.testng.TestNG testng-qc-sanity-regression.xml

And I got `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

**When I execute the project from eclipse works fine, any idea?**

Comment: Please add more context. In order to help you we need to know more about your project and your exact configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first command:

```
java -jar myjar.jar -cp ./bin testng-qc-sanity-regression.xml
```

will try to execute your main class defined in the jar file under META-INF/MANIFEST.MF which is not what you want.

The second command

```
java -cp D:\Profiles\user.m2\repository\org\testng\testng\6.8.5\testng-6.8.5.jar; org.testng.TestNG testng-qc-sanity-regression.xml
```

is not defining the current directory on classpath and there is also a typo in the path.

Try to use the following:

```
java -cp ".;D:\Profiles\user\.m2\repository\org\testng\testng\6.8.5\testng-6.8.5.jar" org.testng.TestNG testng-qc-sanity-regression.xml
```

Comment: Thanks! I finally solve it with :java -cp D:\tm-efiling-selenium-v1.0.0\lib\*;tm-efiling-selenium-v1.0.1.jar;D:\tm-efiling-selenium-v1.0.0\target\classes;D:\tm-efiling-selenium-v1.0.0\target\classes\test-classes org.testng.TestNG testng-qc-sanity-regression.xml