# Error while running TestNG using bat file

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

Why this error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

Occur while running TestNG using bat file?

Comment: Where do you get this error? What are you trying to test and how? Please provide some more information in order to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303723/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-testng-testng)

Answer (score 0):

You must provide `classpath` to `testng` jar using `-cp` argument. also for other dependent jars like selenium and test classes (project)

Try the following command:

```
java -cp J:\temp\testng\*;J:\temp\workspace\TestNGExamples\bin;J:\automation\* org.testng.TestNG J:\temp\workspace\TestNGExamples\testng1.xml
```

Note: please update the paths as per your machine.

For `-cp` argument, given the directory paths to

1. testng jar
2. test classes (project bin directory)
3. selenium jar