# How to execute jar file of a TestNG project in Eclipse

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse, testng.xml

I am able to run a TestNg project in Eclipse by running the testng.xml file. After building the Maven project, I tried to run the jar file in the terminal using the command java -jar jarname.
But it showing an error "no main manifest attribute". So i created a runner class and tried to run that class by run as -> Java application. But it throwing an error "cannot find class in classpath"
My code is given below.

pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>MockTest</groupId>
<artifactId>MockFrameTest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
  </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.28</version>
</dependency>   
</dependencies> 

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>       
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        
    </plugins>
</build>
```

testng.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
<listeners>
  <listener class-name="com.reportListners.testListner"/>
</listeners>
<test name="Test">
<classes>
  
  <class name="com.tests.Login"/>
  <class name="com.tests.Home"/>
  
</classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

runner.java

```
package runner;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.testng.TestNG;

public class TestNGrunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestNG runner=new TestNG();
     
    // Create a list of String 
    List<String> suitefiles=new ArrayList<String>();
     
    // Add xml file which you have to execute
    suitefiles.add(".//testng.xml");
     
    // now set xml file for execution
    runner.setTestSuites(suitefiles);
     
    // finally execute the runner using run method
    runner.run();

 }
}
```

So how can i run this TestNG project using the Jar file. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Look at this answer for pointers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41605614/running-testng-via-command-line

Comment: Or this blog post: https://crashingdaily.wordpress.com/2009/11/12/using-groups-with-testng/